# How to refresh file list in moc?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, documentation

In moc (music on console), I want to refresh the file list, because I have renamed all files to lowercase and moc still shows uppercase for all files that begin with a number.

The help command (h) says that `^r ^l` does `Refresh the screen`, but ctrl+r+l does not seem to work. I see no reaction.

What does `^r ^l` stand for? Which keys on the  keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^` in `^r` in ASCII text files normally stands for pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> plus the following key. In that combination it is more customary to use the lowercase keys, and not the uppercase versions as they appear on (most) keyboards.

Thus:

`^r` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
 `^l` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>